# Microservice client registration in dynamicaly configured module for nest.js and loading into service by parameter

Tags: microservices, nestjs, ioc-container

I used `shared` module with dynamic configuration in application.
Shared module contains `interceptor` and `service` which contains client configured from shared parameters.
I injected the `service` into the `interceptor` by predefined name (importing `SharedModule` dynamically into `SecondAppModule`). So client name can have different value. Inside of service I need to know the clients name before client injecting. Right now it is hard coded:

```
@Injectable()
export class SumClientService {
    constructor(@Inject('MATH_SERVICE') private client: ClientProxy) {
        console.log('[SumClientService] - created')
    }

    sumCalculation(row: number[]): Observable<number> {
        return this.client.send<number>({ cmd: 'sum' }, row);
    }
}
```

### Question

Is there any ways to load service from context by name in case name known at construction time only?

I've detected two ways at list to past name as a parameter into service without corrupting DI managed by `nest.js`. But I have no idea how to get access to module context for loading service by specified name (the code of idea fragment is below)

```
@Injectable()
export class SumClientService {
    constructor(@Inject('service_name') private name: string) {
        console.log('[SumClientService] - created')
        
    }
    client: (clientName: string) => ClientProxy = (clientName: string): ClientProxy => // TODO load by clientName real client from `nest.js` context

// ...
}
```

### P.S.

The idea is to use multiple clients in the same application. I considered scenario one client per module for the first time.

[git code](https://github.com/SergiiVlasiuk/kafka-client-demo/blob/main/nest-multibranch/libs/shared/src/sum-client.service.ts#L7-L14)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are few options to create microservice clients in dynamic module:

### 1st option

in module configuration level:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ClientModule } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { configForYourClient } from '../configs';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ClientModule.register([
      { 'NAME_FOR_DI', ...configForYourClient }
    ])
  ],
...
})
...
```

usage:

```
import { Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ClientProxy } from '@nestjs/microservices';

...
  constructor(@Inject('NAME_FOR_DI') private readonly client:   ClientProxy) { }
```

### 2st option

For dynamically configured module:

```
import { Module, DynamicModule } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ClientModule } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { configForYourClient } from '../configs';

@Module({})
export class YourModule{
  static register(): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: YourModule,
      imports: [
        ClientModule.register([
          { 'NAME_FOR_DI', ...configForYourClient }
        ])
      ],
    }
  }
}
```

### 3st option

```
import { ClientProxy, ClientProxyFactory } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { configForYourClient } from '../configs';

...
  private client: ClientProxy = ClientProxyFactory.create(configForYourClient)
```

Following second option it can be created in service directly or registered for module specifying DI key in providers, like:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ClientProxyFactory } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { configForYourClient } from '../configs';

@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'NAME_FOR_DI',
      useValue: ClientProxyFactory.create(configForYourClient)
    },
  ],
...
})
...
```

with following injection by specified key.

### P.S.

I've described here general idea for dynamic injection. This idea can be enriched with different combinations (injecting list of values for the single provider, or injecting list of configurations into `ClientModule.register` where you should apply some corrections in you DI approach)